# Java Play POST [Parameter Missing] error?

Tags: java, scala, rest, post, playframework

I am building a RESTful API in Play and I am getting a strange error with my routes:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /api/getMessages            controllers.Application.getMessages()
POST    /api/createMessage          controllers.Application.createMessages(from:String, subject:String, message:String)

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

The /api/createMessage is giving me some problems, when I post a full payload to it I get the error:

```
For request 'POST /api/createMessage' [Missing parameter: from]
```

Controller:

```
public static Result createMessages(String from, String subject, String message){
    Message.create(from, subject, message);
    return ok(toJson("ok"));
}
```

Request body:

```
Request Url: http://localhost:9000/api/createMessage
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400
Params: {
    "from": "hello@test.com",
    "subject": "Hello",
    "message": "World"
}
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Added the controller in, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that in order to pass parameters to Java methods through the routes files, these parameters should be part of your endpoint's URL, which should be something similar to `POST     /api/createMessage/:from/:subject/:message`

This is not a good idea for your case, and what you are trying to do (passing the parameters from a json object) is actually the way to go. So what you should do is replace the line in routes file with:

```
POST    /api/createMessage          controllers.Application.createMessages()
```

and read the JSON object from withing the createMessages method:

```
JsonNode data = request().body().asJson();
String from = data.get("from").textValue();
String subject = data.get("subject").textValue();
String message = data.get("message").textValue();
```

Just make sure you pass the **Content-Type: application/json** header with your request, so that play understands the request body as a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

problem is that you are sending data by post in your request

try

```
GET    /api/createMessage          controllers.Application.createMessages(from:String, subject:String, message:String)
```

and

```
Request Method: GET
```

this problem is because your request adding the params in `POST`

or, if you want in POST

```
POST    /api/createMessage          controllers.Application.createMessages
```

controller

```
public static Result createMessages{
String form =  //get it
String subject =  //get it
String message =  //get it
//not aware of java syntax too much but get here from form
Message.create(from, subject, message);
return ok(toJson("ok"));
}
```

as you tag of **scala**, means you are familar with scala so in scala controller be

```
def createMessages = Action{
     implicit request =>
    val form = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("form")(0)
    var subject = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("subject")(0)
    var message = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("message")(0)
    Message.create(from, subject, message)
    OK("ok")
}
```

Comment: I want it to be post, I don't wish for the route to be a GET

Comment: @JacobClark updated the answer hope it will help you